# Delete own question or answer via mobile app

Tags: feature-request, answers, questions, android-app

I have lost count of the times I posted a question just to one minute later figure out the solution myself. And more frequently then I would like, posted an answer to shortly after someone notice a mistake.

As far as I know, there is no option to delete one's own question or answer when using the mobile app. Sometimes it can be bothersome to open another browser just to do so.

I went through all questions in meta with the tag `feature-request` and found no discussion about this. I understand that here in meta is the correct place to ask: is it possible to add these features in the mobile app? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an issue that concerns the entire network. The relevant feature request exists since a long time on the main meta [Allow us to vote to delete from the Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216962/allow-us-to-vote-to-delete-from-the-android-app)

It is alright to have it here locally, too, but I am afraid the usefulness will be limited. In any case, I recommend you and everybody that cares for this should up-vote the request on the main meta.

Comment: You're right, I missed that detail. Thanks for pointing!